# Table unknown in procedure autonomous transaction statement in Firebird

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, firebird-psql, firebird-4.0

I have to create table and insert data into it. The operation isn't meant to be repeated often, but we need some kind of automation.

I use autonomous transaction, but get the same error. According to [release notes](https://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rnfb25-psql-exctstmnt.html):

> The WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION setting starts a new transaction with
> the same parameters as CURRENT_TRANSACTION. That transaction will be
> committed if the statement is executed....

Why is the exception thrown (Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -204. Table unknown.)?

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE write_sh_record_with_clenup (
    tagid TYPE OF COLUMN "SNAPSHOT".tagid,
    scannername VCHAR30_REQ)
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE tablename TABLE_NAME;
  DECLARE PROCEDURE create_sh_table (name TABLE_NAME)
  AS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE STATEMENT 'CREATE TABLE "' || :name || '" (tagid TAG_ID, dateyear DATE_PART, dayofyear DATE_PART, totalseconds SECONDS_TIMESTAMP, "VALUE" DOUBLE PRECISION);'
    WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION;
    WHEN ANY DO
    BEGIN
      EXCEPTION ex_custom USING (UPPER('create_sh_table'), GDSCODE, SQLCODE, SQLSTATE);
    END
  END
BEGIN
  :tablename = 'SH_' || :scannername;
  IF (get_table_exists(:tablename) = 'F') THEN
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_sh_table(:tablename);
  EXECUTE STATEMENT 'INSERT INTO ' || :tablename || ' SELECT * FROM snapshot WHERE tagid = ' || :tagid || ';';
END
```

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 4.0.4.3010

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Moreover I've also tried to use parameterised statements instead of OR concatenation, either '?' or ':p_name' isn't recognised (token unknown), if it'll come in handy for you.

Comment: That is irrelevant for this problem, and that sounds like you're doing something wrong, like trying to use a parameter for the table name, which is not possible.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel explain once again, please.  I haven't found any information about permissions on parameters. As parameterised statement is any DDL/DML statement, and a table name can be passed to procedure, why it's not possible to execute it without error as it's kind of parsed and interpreted by the engine in runtime?

Comment: I'm saying it is not possible to use something like `insert into ? (column1) values ('value')`, that is you cannot parameterize an object name, only values (i.e. `insert into some_table (column1) values (?)`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, only values, now I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this with isolation level SNAPSHOT or SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY, this is entirely expected: your procedure can only see the state of other transactions that were committed before its transaction started: it will not be able to see the changes of the autonomous transaction. If you're using READ COMMITTED, it is also expected behaviour *since* Firebird 4.0.

Firebird 4.0 introduced a new way of handling READ COMMITTED transactions, [*read committed read consistency*](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/4_0/rlsnotes40.html#rnfb40-engine-read-consistency), and this is enabled [by default](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/4_0/rlsnotes40.html#rnfb40-compat-read-consistency), even if mode *read committed record_version* or *no record_version* is requested.

With this *read consistency* mode, a statement will see the state of committed transactions as they were *before* the statement started. In the case of a stored procedure, that statement is the DSQL `select` or `execute procedure` that directly or indirectly called the procedure.

As a result, even though you created the table in an autonomous transaction, and that transaction was committed, as far as the outer procedure is concerned, it doesn't exist as that transaction was committed *after* it started.

The real solution is to not create tables on the fly like this, but create them ahead of time, but alternatively, you have two workarounds:

1. Disable the setting `ReadConsistency` in firebird.conf by setting it to `0` instead of its default of `1`, and make sure your transaction is started as `READ COMMITTED RECORD_VERSION` or `READ COMMITTED NO RECORD_VERSION` (and not as `READ COMMITTED READ CONSISTENCY`).

   I do not recommend this option, as this is intended as a transitional configuration, and will eventually disappear: do not rely on it, you'll only delay the pain of having to address this.
2. Execute the insert with an autonomous transaction as well.

   This is only a viable workaround if you don't need to be able to see uncommitted changes from the current transaction during the insert.

Comment: I also don't wan't to deal with temporary configuration as it's the matter of time when it becomes obsolete. To sum up: when you said to create beforehand you mean, e.g. another procedure (where I can check if table exists using 'rdb$relations name)?

Comment: As a second option you suggested using autonomous transaction with insert too. Now I'm wondering about that autonomous transaction? How will it figures out if table in the create transaction succeded?

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov Ideally, your schema should be stable, and not require on-the-fly creation of objects, but essentially, yes, if you need to do this on the fly, you'll need to separately execute a procedure to create the table from the procedure that populates the table (these must be separate DSQL calls, you can't call these two procedure from another procedure, because that would be considered a single statement for the purpose of read consistency).

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov As to your second question, given you raise an exception when table creation fails, it will never execute the insert. The fact you use an autonomous transaction doesn't mean it ignores the normal error handling flow.

Comment: Works like a charm. You are a lifesaver. Chapter 12. Transaction Control of firebird manual is about read consistency (I plan to read the whole thing, but at the moment the most necessary ones due to lack of time) am I right? The second question will be: which of the two ways of solving this task would you chose?

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov Well, I'd try to avoid either by avoiding the need to create tables on the fly, but if I have to choose, I prefer the second workaround.